# How to bind "Paste as text" tinymce command with custom button

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I am using tinymce editor in my code. Here is my code

```
tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode : "textareas",
    plugins : "paste",
    theme_advanced_disable:"pasteword,selectall"       

});
```

Is there any way for create custom button on tinymce toolbar and bind custom button with "Paste as text" command.

Please help.